# Replace all rgb values above a threshold

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rgb

I have a numpy 3 d array full of RGB values like for exemple
shape = (height,width,3)

```
  matrix = np.array( [[[0,0.5,0.6],[0.9,1.2,0]])
```

I have to replace the RGB value if any of the values is above a threshold, for exemple threshold = 0.8, replacement = [2,2,2] then

```
matrix = [[[0,0.5,0.6],[2,2,2]]
```

How can I do this on a efficient mannner with numpy ?
Currently I am using a double for loop and checking if any rgb value is above treshold, i replace it however this is quiet slow for n = 4000 array.

How would I do this more efficient with numpy, maybe something with np.where ?

Comment: Your square brackets don't match, are you having a 3D matrix or a 2D matrix?

Comment: Find the rows using masking and then index into the array and assign your replacement values

Comment: 3 d array, (height,width,3) is the shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've expanded your matrix by another `width` dimension.

```
matrix = np.array([[[0,0.5,0.6],[0.9,1.2,0]],[[0,0.5,0.6],[0.9,1.2,0]]])
```

You can build a mask by using `np.any` on axis 2 (starts with 0, so third axis):

```
mask = np.any((matrix > 0.8), axis=2)

# mask:
array([[False,  True],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)

matrix[mask] = np.array([2,2,2])
```

Your resulting `matrix`:

```
array([[[ 0. ,  0.5,  0.6],
        [ 2. ,  2. ,  2. ]],

       [[ 0. ,  0.5,  0.6],
        [ 2. ,  2. ,  2. ]]])
```