# Changing the values of a matrix above a threshold in python

Tags: python, image-processing, matrix, threshold, image-thresholding

I have a matrix :

```
matrix = np.array([[[0,0.5,0.6],[0.9,1.2,0]],[[0,0.5,0.6],[0.9,1.2,0]]])
```

I want to replace all the values `0.55 < x < 0.95` by `0.55`.

PS : My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836490/replace-all-rgb-values-above-a-threshold). But the answer does not work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
matrix = np.array([[[0,0.5,0.6],[0.9,1.2,0]],[[0,0.5,0.6],[0.9,1.2,0]]])
matrix[np.where((matrix > 0.55) & (matrix < 0.95))] = 0.55
# Or
# matrix[(matrix > 0.55) & (matrix < 0.95)] = 0.55
```

Output:

```
>>> matrix
array([[[0.  , 0.5 , 0.55],
        [0.55, 1.2 , 0.  ]],

       [[0.  , 0.5 , 0.55],
        [0.55, 1.2 , 0.  ]]])
```